# How to write view for any HTML name?

Tags: django

I am transforming my code to django and have many HTML files and serve them to user. So currently I write:

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [    
    url(r'^1.html$', views.display1),    
    url(r'^2.html$', views.display2),    
    url(r'^3.html$', views.display2) ...
```

views.py:

```
def display1(request):
    return render(request,'1.html')

def display2(request):
    return render(request,'2.html')

def display3(request):
    return render(request,'3.html')
```

I am sure this is an extremely ugly way. What is the correct way to write such functionality in django? (what is the term for what I am looking for so that I can google it)

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using Django at all to serve flat HTML files. Use a static web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the tutorial.

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^(?P<page>\d+)\.html$', views.display)
]
```

...

```
def display(request, page):
  verify(page) # Implementation left as an exercise for the reader
  return render(request, '{}.html'.format(page))
```

Comment: Thank you.  which "tutorial" do you mean? What is the term so that I can google it?